# Custom Lint Rule to Check All Views in Layouts

Tags: android, lint

In the app I'm working on, it is imperative that all views in all layout files have an `id` set on them. So I'm trying to build a custom lint rule to enforce this.

Normally, one would use the `getApplicableElements()` method from `XmlScanner` and include a list of strings for each element tag. However, I can't seem to find a way to make this look at all elements in an XML layout which subclass `View`.

I tried using `XmlScannerConstants.ALL`, however, that looks at every single element in every single XML file. Given that we have several other types of XML-based resources, that's not going to work.

My code for the inspector class is below. Does anyone know of a good way filter `getApplicableElements()` so it looks at every element that subclasses `View`, and nothing else?

```
class IdDetector : ResourceXmlDetector() {

    companion object {

        private const val ISSUE_ID = "MissingId"
        private const val ISSUE_DESCRIPTION = "Missing required attribute 'id'"
        private const val ISSUE_EXPLANATION = "Identifiers are required on all views."

        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
            id = ISSUE_ID,
            briefDescription = ISSUE_DESCRIPTION,
            explanation = ISSUE_EXPLANATION,
            category = Category.A11Y,
            priority = 10,
            severity = Severity.FATAL,
            androidSpecific = true,
            implementation = Implementation(IdDetector::class.java, Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE)
        )
    }

    override fun getApplicableElements(): Collection<String>? = XmlScannerConstants.ALL

    override fun visitElement(context: XmlContext, element: Element) {
        if (!element.hasAttributeNS("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id")) {
            context.report(ISSUE, element, context.getLocation(element), ISSUE_DESCRIPTION)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the `appliesTo(@NonNull ResourceFolderType folderType)` method that can help you achieve that. In your case, I believe you will be only interested in targeting the layout folder. You're new detector would look something like this:

```kotlin
class IdDetector : ResourceXmlDetector() {

    companion object {

        private const val ISSUE_ID = "MissingId"
        private const val ISSUE_DESCRIPTION = "Missing required attribute 'id'"
        private const val ISSUE_EXPLANATION = "Identifiers are required on all views."

        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
            id = ISSUE_ID,
            briefDescription = ISSUE_DESCRIPTION,
            explanation = ISSUE_EXPLANATION,
            category = Category.A11Y,
            priority = 10,
            severity = Severity.FATAL,
            androidSpecific = true,
            implementation = Implementation(IdDetector::class.java, Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE)
        )
    }

    override fun appliesTo(folderType: ResourceFolderType): Boolean = ResourceFolderType.LAYOUT == folderType

    override fun getApplicableElements(): Collection<String>? = XmlScannerConstants.ALL

    override fun visitElement(context: XmlContext, element: Element) {
        if (!element.hasAttributeNS("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id")) {
            context.report(ISSUE, element, context.getLocation(element), ISSUE_DESCRIPTION)
        }
    }
}
```